# When I move the armature which is rigged to my plane, it makes an extra face

Tags: modeling, mesh, rigging, bones

I am trying to do some origami in blender and have succeeded in rigging the plane. The rig works by rotating the Control bone and the other bone rotates inverse to the Control bone. The folding works but when the fold happens, an extra face is added as seen in the video below.

[image]

This is the Blend file.
[image]

Thanks!

Comment: you probably have an unwanted face here, remove it in Edit mode

Comment: @moonboots I can confirm your suspicions. I downloaded the file to check for precisely that.

Comment: OMG im an idiot... Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

You have somehow created an unwanted face here, activate the *On Cage* option of the *Armature* modifier, select the face in *Edit* mode and remove it:

[image]